# How does HttpTestingController work in Angular5?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, httpclient

I have to mock http requests in unit tests. All examples in internet suggesting to make original request first and then mock requests like the following.

```
it('should mock the requests', (done) => {
  const testUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/api/users';
  const service = TestBed.get(SomeService);
    service
       .getUserData()
       .then((users) => {
        expect(users.length).toBe(3);
        done();
        })
       .catch(done.fail)
httpMock.expectOne(testUrl).flush(users);
httpMock.verify();
});
```

Why I have to make original request first ? and then Mock the request? When actually the mock response I flushed will get by the getUserData() method ?

Also, If the getUserData() method in service has two or more api calls in it, I end up with the following error

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

How can I mock multiple http calls?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: *Original* request is never made. It's mocked request, that's the point. If you do 2 requests to different urls, you should have 2 httpMock.expectOne.

Comment: oh yeah, I did two httpMock.expectOne, but it either ends up `with Async callback was not invoked ....` error or  `Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: http://localhost:3001/api/***", found none.` error.

Comment: Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The question doesn't contain the code you're testing.